# JS Form validation issue

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS ! This is my first program. It validates that the text field shouldn't be null. I tried everthing but nothing seems to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data_age = document.getElementById("ages") ;

    function check() {
        if (data_age==null) {
            alert("no data") ;
            return false ;
        } else {
            return true ;
        }   
    }
</script>


<form name="frm" action="a.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check(this)">
<input type="text" name="age" id="ages">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `data_age` is defined outside the scope of `check()`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a variable contains a text field, it is never equal to `null` for the exact reason it is a text field. (`getElementById` can return `null` in case the element does not exist, though.) You want to check whether *its value is empty or not*. You can use `data_age.value === ""` for that (getting the value and comparing it against the empty string).

Second, you call `getElementById` before you define the element in HTML. You could swap the `<form>` and `<script>` elements so that the element is there at the time you call `getElementById`. Also, use `var data_age = ...`.

Comment: Thanks mate ! It was so helpfull !!

Comment: Actually, if element with the given ID does not exist, it *will* be null.

Comment: @SaurabhShukla check for the name Douglas Crockford for JavaScript learning. You can find a bunch of videos on youtube about him talking about JS.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Then it's not a text field :-)

Comment: @pim yeah, but still - from your first sentence it sounds like you say "document.getElementById will never return null" which is not true. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Thanks, I changed the wording.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var isBlank = function (str) {
        return str == null || str.trim().length == 0;
    }

function check()
{

var data_age = document.getElementById("ages") ;
if (isBlank(data_age.value))
{
alert("no data") ;
return false ;
}
else
{
return true ;
}   
}
</script>


<form name="frm" action="a.php" method="post" onsubmit="return check(this)">
<input type="text" name="age" id="ages">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: This will fail in IE version less than 9 (no generic `trim()` function). Why complicate things so much?

Answer (score 1):

You should add  var data_age = document.getElementById("ages") ; inside function.

```
 function check()
        {
            var data_age = document.getElementById("ages") ;
            if (data_age.value == "")
            {
            alert("no data") ;
            return false ;
            }  
        }
```